# input wget exclusions from a file?

Tags: wget, exclude

i'm crawling a forum and I keep stumbling across certain threads that have been going on for ten years.

i can certainly exclude these using wget option:

-X /t/41866,/t/314849,/t/335041,/t/356321,/t/491462,/t/493609,/t/493655,/t/493667,/t/493668,/t/493676,/t/493678

and I can also exclude them by inserting the string in the wgetrc file

but what i'd like to do is just call a file that contains the string, like you can do with the -i option where you call a file that pulls in the URLs of interest

so instead of (from the GNU wget 1.11.4 manual)

exclude directories = string
Specify a comma-separated list of directories you wish to exclude from download—
the same as ‘-X string’

so i'd like the string to actually pull in the contents of a file.  is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just use the shell

```
wget -X `head -n1 exclude_file` blah
```

the `head -n1` is incase there is a trailing newline in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-I list` or `--include-directories=list` option:

```
   -I list
   --include-directories=list
       Specify a comma-separated list of directories you wish to follow when downloading.  Elements
       of list may contain wildcards.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -X `perl -MFile::Slurp -e '@lines=read_file("./FILE.txt"); chop @lines; print join ",", @lines'`
```

(you may need to install File::Slurp Perl module).